# Android intent filter pathpattern for multiple folder levels

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, deep-linking

I have URIs like this: http://myapp/category/details and 3 activities that should handle different levels of this structure.
Activity 1 should handle http://myapp
Activity 2 should handle http://myapp/category
Activity 3 should handle http://myapp/category/details
I have problems with finding the combination of right path/pathPattern/pathPrefix for the data tag. In the example below all 3 activities are happy to handle uri like this http://myapp/category/details and the "Complete action using" dialog is displayed with 3 icons of myapp.
Activity 1:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="http"
    android:host="myapp"
</intent-filter>
```

Activity 2:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="http"
    android:host="myapp"
    android:pathPattern="/.*"
</intent-filter>
```

Activity 3:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="http"
    android:host="myapp"
    android:pathPattern="/.*/.*"
</intent-filter>
```

How to prevent activity 1 from handling the links intended for activity 2 & 3?
(And activity 2 handling links for activity 3)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mime` in order to distinguish between the intent

```
<data android...
 android:mimeType: "your specific mime for the intent...can be custom one like activity/activity1
>
```

then to run your specific `Intent` using mime do something like

```
intent.setType("mimeType/mimeSubType");
if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```

You can also (and should) use `pathPrefix` in order to distinguish between the paths.

Have a look at [data element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html) for more info